# OnCheckedChanged Listener for multiple switches with the same ID

Tags: java, android, xml

My app has a settings page, where users have their email and phone number preferences. For each phone number, there are two switches (Voice and SMS). There's just one switch per email, indicating whether or not it is active.

Many users will only have 1 phone, 1 email. But theoretically, users can have an infinite number of emails and phone numbers (loaded from the API), and they will all be reflected on this Settings page.

The problem is that I technically only have 3 switches, “voiceSwitch”, “smsSwitch” and “emailSwitch” for all the rows, no matter how many rows there are. So even if a user has 3 different phone numbers, I believe they would all have the same ID… is that correct?

How can I do a ‘listener’ to see if ANY of the switches have been checked? I need to do this because I'm trying to update the user settings whenever a switch is changed. I don't know how to properly reference individual phone/email switches.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rn2R4WC

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you used any databinding? It would really help to see what you have done and proceed.

Comment: You could add the item position as tag to each switch and in checkChangedListener, use the tag as index.

Comment: this depends, how are you creating these switches ? do you make a layout for them or are you using a recycler view ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody This involves 3 XML files: "settings_activity.xml" which has 2 listviews (phoneList and emailList), "phone_list_row.xml" which just has a label for the number and the 2 switches, and "email_list_row.xml" which has the label and 1 switch. I am not technically using a RecyclerView but I am sort of 'recycling' these views? I am using these phone and email rows as each row of the listview. please help! I can post the code for filling the rows if necessary?

Comment: let me see what i can come up with, different time zones really makes this hard :P

Comment: ok so, you have a listview of items and you want to set ALL the switches to either on or off, right ?

Comment: damn, was hoping my answer would be enough :) 
so you're saying that you simply want to update the api every time a switch changes ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody that's correct! I'm assuming I need a listener for the switches in the listviews, and I will need to know which switches belong to which email / phone number so I can update their settings correctly

Comment: ahh, sorry for the misunderstanding :P so, as you are binding the views in the list (let me know if you understand what this means or not) all you have to do is to set listeners to the switches to update the api as they change